# How to make a boundary in 2d

Tags: c#

I an trying to keep my charecter inside boundaries but I was only able to get it to work for the side walls and not the bottem and top walls. Here is my code for moving and the boundaries.

````
{
    public float verticalInput;
    public float horizontalInput;
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    public float Xrange = 9.5f;
    public float Yrange = 4.0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput =  Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime * speed);

        verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime *  speed);

         if (transform.position.x < -Xrange)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(-Xrange, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
       
        if (transform.position.x > Xrange)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(Xrange, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }

        if (transform.position.y < -Yrange)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(-Yrange, transform.position.x, transform.position.z);
        }
       
        if (transform.position.y > Yrange)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(Yrange, transform.position.x, transform.position.z);
        } ```
````

Comment: "2d" does not have "top" and "bottom" (if it already used up 2 dimensions for other checks). Please clarify what you trying to achieve.

Comment: I mean that I am trying to make a boundary for the top and bottem edges of the game view screen so the player cant go out of view.

Comment: @potatohead In your vertical transformations you write `Vector3(-Yrange, transform.position.x ...`. Should that not be `Vector3(transform.position.x, -Yrange ...` etc.? I thought it's always x, y, z fields in that order.